# NW.js: If both arrays are equal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-webkit, nwjs

I'm working on an IDE as a side project using [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) and I need to detect if there's any changes to my project tree when focused.

I'm using [JQuery's .each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) check if the files in the project folder have changed since being focused.

Here's what I have for window focused function.

```
win.on("focus", function() {
  var stringArray = [];
  listFiles = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/content/project");
  console.log("checking if there's any changes");
  $.each($("[data-nme]"), function() {
    stringArray.push(this.textContent);
  });
  var array1 = listFiles;
  var array2 = JSON.stringify(stringArray);

  console.log(array1);
  console.log(array2);

  if (array1.toString() != array2.toString()) {
    console.log("there's been a change");
  }
});
```

When I debug I get the following result.

[image]

I don't understand why it says there's a difference with the array when it's the exact same.

```
if (array1.toString() != array2.toString()) {
  console.log("there's been a change");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the way you check equality. One of the array is JSON.stringified the other is not. Don't use JSON.stringify(stringArray) for defining array2.

```
var foo = ["bar"];
foo.toString();
```

Outputs : `"foo"`

```
JSON.stringify(foo).toString()
```

Outputs : `"["foo"]"`

This condition should be working (haven't tested) :

```
 if (array1.toString() != stringArray.toString()) {
    console.log("there's been a change");
  }
```

if you want the best option to compare arrays check this one :
[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)